# Is the use of "9-sibling" and "13-year" in the sentence below correct?

Tags: hyphens

> ...has been a realtor for **13-year** and decided, at a young age, that he wanted to make selling real estate a career. Being raised in a large family of **9-siblings**

Comment: The hyphens aside, the number of years is greater than one: it should be 13 year**s**, as in a plural

Answer (score 24):

You should not use hyphens in these instances.

We do not hyphenate such noun phrases when they are used in ordinary nominal contexts such as object of a preposition or argument (subject, object, complement) of a verb:

> He has been a realtor for thirteen years.
>   Thirteen years have passed since he entered the real estate business.
>   He has spent thirteen years in the real estate business.
>   It has been thirteen years since he entered the real estate business.

We only employ the hyphen when the noun phrase is employed as an attributive:

> ... his thirteen-year career as a realtor ...

The hyphen is a courtesy to reader, making clear that the *year* is not the noun which ends the noun phrase launched with *his* but part of a subordinate constituent along the way.

Note that when we marry quantified noun phrases as attributives like this the noun loses its ordinary plurality: *a thirteen-year career*, *a nine-sibling family*.

Note, too, that when the quantified noun phrase is employed as a genitive it retains its plurality and is **not** hyphenated: *his thirteen years' experience*.

Answer (score 14):

**No.**

Firstly: neither phrase needs a hyphen. The use of hyphens can be tricky, but here the relevant rule is that they are used to make *compound modifiers*. Use a hyphen to link a modifier to another word, when the two together then modify something else.

> He is **well liked**. *("Well" modifies "like".)*
>
> He is a **well-liked** person. *("Well" modifies "like", and together they modify "person".)*

Both of your cases are more similar to the first example above. You would only use a hyphen if it was instead written like so:

> ...has had a **13-year** career as a realtor. Being raised in a **9-sibling** family...

Secondly: in your sentence, "13-year" (or, as it should be, "13 year") is incorrect because "year" should be plural, "years".

(Note that the example I just put above *is* correct as "13-year", however, because nouns like "year" stay singular when used as modifiers to other nouns.)

Fully corrected:

> ...has been a realtor for 13 years and decided, at a young age, that he wanted to make selling real estate a career. Being raised in a large family of 9 siblings...

Comment: Is the hyphen in the second sentence's "well-liked" necessary? As an adverb, "well" cannot modify "person", so it should be a given that it modifies the following adjective.

Comment: @chepner "well" can also be an adjective meaning "not ill".

Comment: I think I was assuming you would use a comma in that case. ("He is a well, liked person.", which is already a bit stilted anyway.)

Comment: A career of 13 years is a 13-year career, not a 13-years career. See answer of @StoneyB

Comment: @Lenne: Quite right. After reading StoneyB's answer, I realised that my answer seemed to be saying that *my own* example should've been "13-years". I didn't edit it right away because I wanted to see if a correction was needed... maybe nobody would think that's what I meant? But you did, and so I've edited it. :-)